# '.....' object is not iterable in django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models: User, Choice, Card. Each user will look at the same set of 10 cards and decides each one is important or not.

Here are how I define the classes and their relationship

In models.py:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    card = models.ManyToManyField(Card)
    is_important = models.NullBooleanField()

class Card(models.Model):
    card_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=False)
```

In views.py

(I try to save the choice for the card from the user. )

```
def listings(request):
   user = request.user
   choice = Choice.objects.create(user=user, is_important = True)
   choice.card= Card.objects.get(1)
```

However, I got this error

```
'Card' object is not iterable
```

Could you please show me where the error is?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Card.objects.get(1)` is not valid django syntax. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Did you mean to use `choice.card = Card.objects.get(card_number = your_number)` instead?

Comment: Also if written correctly it would return one car object, not many.

Comment: Thank you all! I am new to Django and under pressure of deadline so I don't have time to read Django structurally from the beginning to get the foundation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function:

```
def listings(request):
   user = request.user
   choice = Choice.objects.create(user=user, is_important = True)
   choice.card= Card.objects.get(1)
```

The following line is trying to fetch the Card object. However, we need to specify which card to be fetched.
If using an id, query it as:

```
 choice.card= Card.objects.get(pk=1)
```

or else using list of ids:

```
 choice.card = Card.objects.filter(pk__in=[12,22])
```

If using card_number field:

```
 choice.card= Card.objects.get(card_number=1)
```

or else using list of card_numbers:

```
 choice.card = Card.objects.filter(card_number__in=[12,22])
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it looks like you forgot `pk=` in your first `.get()` argument:  `Card.objects.get(pk=1)`

Second, `Choice.cards` is a ManyToManyField that expects a list of items and not one in particular. You should set it through:

```
choice.card.set(Card.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

Please note that direct assignment with `=` [will be deprecated from Django 1.10 and deleted in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)

`.filter()` will return a QuerySet (which is iterable). I think you wanted a `ForeignKey` instead of a M2M field, in which case your code would work (with the additional `pk=`).

Answer (score 3):

You can add object against many to many field like this

```
card =  Card.objects.create(card_number=any_number, content='abc')   
choice.card.add(card)
```